# websocketでウェブサーバーを構築したい。

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, websocket, leap-motion

私は**RaspberryPi3**を使い**Leapmotion**を制御しようを考えていたのですが、**RaspberryPi3**に直接**Leamotion**をつなぐことはできないと学びました。PCに**Leapmotion**を接続し、**WebServer**上で**RaspberryPi3**がそのPCから**Leapmotion**のデータを取ってくるしか方法がないと最近知ったのですが、**JavaScript**で**WebServer**の立ち上げ方が調べても全く分かりません。簡単なところなのかもしれませんが教えてほしいです。

Answer (score 1):

[ドキュメント](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/devguide/Leap_Architecture.html)によれば、

> The Leap Motion service runs a WebSocket server on the localhost domain at port 6437.

との事ですので、質問者さんが作ろうとしているサーバーは SDK に含まれています。
つまり、自分で作る必要はありません。